# How can I make java check for an image on the screen and run a piece of code if its there?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a bot that plays a web game, I looked it up on google and I didn't find anything useful, all I found was how to find the color for a pixel, so how do I find an image on the screen, and how can I make java start by scanning for it from the bottom?

Comment: Please make an attempt at first. Divide the problem into smaller problems and solve them one by one. The smaller problems usually have answers on google...

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. I'm with @ItamarGreen, in that you need to first do more research before asking, and when asking, showing the fruits of your research efforts with your question.

Comment: Sorry, im still new to stack overflow so by questions aren't that well described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to use the pixel color checking thing you talked about. You could make a method comparing colors of pixels on the screen with colors of pixels on some reference image. Although in most online games to make a bot it would be enough to check like 4 pixels.